# HTML text not changing when button pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make text change to different text when a button is pressed and I'm not sure why it's not working.

```html
<p id="test"> A </p>

<button onclick = "test()"> Click </button>

<script>
function test(){
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "B";
}
</script>
```

Comment: That code worked for me? https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/29tr1p4e/

Comment: Nevermind, it does work, you're right. document.getElementById wasn't indented correctly, it was off by one space...

Comment: @DarthSwashbuckler — You should delete the question then.

Comment: It says I can't delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use innerText insteadof innerHTML like this:

```
<p id="test"> A </p>

<button onclick = "test()"> Click </button>

<script>
function test(){
     document.getElementById("test").innerText = "B";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.test__button');

button.addEventListener("click", test)

function test() {
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "B";
}
```

```html
<p id="test"> A </p>

<button class="test__button"> Click </button>
```